# SQL using calculated from previous row

Tags: mysql, database

I need to calculate a forecast value from the previous actual and previous forecast. I can get the previous actual but I cannot get previous forecast.
I need to forecast using this formula

```
f_t = k1*a_t-1 + k2*f_t-1
```

where f is the forecast, a is the actual, t is the current time, t-1 is the previous time, k1 and k2 are some constants

I tried this but it calculated using the old value.

```
SELECT t1.id, k1*t2.a + k2*t2.f
FROM table1 t1, table1 t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id + 1
```

[image: How the table should look]